# UITableViewController View Wont Push!

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I cant get my views to switch!

In SettingsViewController.M <-- UITableViewController: loaded from a tabbar. My original application is a tabbar+navigationcontroller. What do I need to push it to cuz navigationcontroller won't work

```
 CompanyProfileViewController *profile = [[CompanyProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CompanyProfileView" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];
```

CompanyProfileViewController <-- UITableViewController

I originally wanted this to have a header/footer and tableview, not sure how to set this up, butevery time I try to push to it, it does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure that (1) the navigation controller is not nil, and (2) that the navigation controller's view is actually a subview of whatever view you have on screen?

Comment: Actually, I'm having the same problem. I have a class that inherits from a UITableViewController and I don't use a nib to initialize it. The inherited navigationController is in nil. How can I create a navigationController in this case? Thanks